# Keeping content across mutliple Linux instances up to date

Tags: linux, nginx, azure

I am running a Linux VM in Azure (nginx). I want to add multiple instances so that it can be load balanced. What I can't get my head around is how I change, for instance, the nginx conf and apply it to all the instances.

Do I need to write a script to copy the conf files to each instance, then script up sending remote nginx -s reload to each one?

What if I want to add a new instance, my image is now out of date presumably, so I think I'd need to create the new instance and fire the afore mentioned script at it?

Answer (score 2):

That is a task for a Configuration Management System. There are multiple of them like [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/), [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/) or [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home). If you only want to keep a basic configuration you could look at Ansible, as it's simpler.

Another option could be using something simpler like [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) to push configurations from your workstations. You can see in nice tutorial in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-fabric-to-automate-administration-tasks-and-deployments

Comment: Yup... ansible would be my number one choice here too. Simple and efficient.

Comment: it does look good, if expensive. I'll investigate the options suggested, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Azure Files Storage for sharing configuration. It is SMB as a Service and it is possible to mount it on many VMs in Your virtual network. You can change files on share with REST API (it is CRUD). It is much simpler in implementation than Ansible, but Ansible is better for overall administration tasks.

Comment: That sounds interesting. I'll have to try and find out more about it.